# what is the ISP loss associated with pressure fed engines

Tags: engine-design, pressure, fuel-system, pressure-fed-engine

Numerically, what is the approximate loss of overall system specific impulse associated with pressure-fed rocket engines, not only as a result of the low chamber pressure but also of the additional tank weight? This is obviously a bit awkward to calculate as the volume of fuel doesn't scale linearly with the surface area of the tank, but even if your answer could include just a rough estimate, that would be really helpful.

Comment: The tank weight doesn't affect specific impulse. (Well, it affects [*system* specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System-specific_impulse), but that's a rarely-mentioned figure.)

Comment: "Loss" relative to what?